# Could you please explain the following code, especially the func statement

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Explain this in detail (every line of the code), I understand what it does but I'm struggling to explain it as notes within the code:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

let text = (lvl1_textfield.text! as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)

if text.isEmpty{
        guess_enter.hidden = true
    } else {
        guess_enter.hidden = false
    } 
    return true
}
```

Comment: We are not a free documentation writing service.

Comment: I think you can try in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Flagging this for off topic since it seems like what you need is an off site service or tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have any doubts regarding the UITextFieldDelegate [see this example](http://sourcefreeze.com/uitextfield-and-uitextfield-delegate-in-swift/).

This func is called just before the typed charecter comes to the textfield. This func is mainly used for the validation.

Just to understand what happens I have written small code.

```
 func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    print("TextField \(textField.text!), Range \(range), string \(string)")
    return true;
 }
```

When I type n the console prints ->>> TextField , Range (0,0), string n

Next If i press a the console prints ->>> TextField n, Range (1,0), string a

Next If i press v the console prints ->>> TextField na, Range (2,0), string v

In the second line where you are declaring **text** your taking the string present in the textView and the recently typed character and appending using the range and then code checks for the empty criteria.

Comment: Please don't answer very low quality questions.